# Java - Execute method on specific date

Tags: java, date, methods, time, execute

I need to execute a method on a specific date of every year, how could I do this in java?

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: did you mean to execute a method or an application (a java program)?

Comment: Is this application going to run forever?

Comment: Yes say on the 1st January of every year some method in Java is executed.

Comment: Is it a web application running in a servlet container?

Answer (score 4):

In order of preference:

1. The [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) library (highly recommended).
2. `java.util.Timer`. Not as powerful as Quartz, but good for simple jobs.
3. The EJB timer service. It's poorly documented, it requires a full Java EE container, and it doesn't really do anything that Quartz doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Timer Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

The method:

```
scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, Date firstTime, long period) 
          Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-rate execution, beginning at the specified time.
```

will allow you to do what you want.  Just be sure you are using the correct date.

Looking at the API, you will need to define a `TimerTask` that overloads the run() method.  The run() method will contain the method you want to call.

Answer (score 3):

If you need something more robust, you can also use Quartz for Cron like scheduling

Answer (score -3):

This will get the current date and time.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

private String getDateTime() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

Then make a loop that checks the function every second and use an if statement to execute the code you want if the time is the time you want.

Comment: How could I code the if statement to work with the date?

Comment: I've made a prototype that I'm testing now. If it works I'll let you know.

Comment: Re-inventing the wheel?