# How to run a specific method on a specific date and time?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I need to force my java application to perform a couple of actions on a specific date and time. The scenario is as following:

```
1- user set a specific time and frequency (every day, every month)
2- system starts a trigger for the request

3- once that pre-defined frequency and time are reached 
 3.1 - system performs the required actions that are kept in a method
```

I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295187/java-execute-method-on-specific-date) but could not make it work.

An example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple java scheduler frameworks available to do the tasks at your specified time, interval, periodicity. [Apache quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) is one of the commonly used ones.

or simply make use of java [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Answer (score 2):

Quartz library is very useful for this.

How to do using Quartz: refer this http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/quartz-scheduler-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) from jdk itself, here is kick off example:

```
 ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
 ScheduledFuture<?> handle scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { System.out.println("your code is here :)"); }
        }, 1, 100, TimeUnit.MINUT);
```

so this code starts running after 1 min and runs after each 100 min.

in order to cancel later you will do `handle.cancel(true)`

Read from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)